# Skin Game - latest Dresden Novel

Tags: the-dresden-files, jim-butcher

In the newest book, Dresden comments on page 139 that

> "...I really didn't feel like making a run on Hades' vault..."

However, at that point in the book, (and I have not gone back to read it over) I'm not certain he knew they were going to Hell.

I was wondering if anyone else had seen the discrepancy or if I had missed an earlier reference.

Comment: If you could add a little more background to the question (and only use 1 question mark instead of 3) that would improve the question

Comment: In the newest book, Dresden comments that "...I really didn't feel like making a run on Hades' vault..." On page 139. However, at that point in the book, (and I have not gone back to read it over) I'm not certain he knew they were going to Hell.  I was wondering if anyone else had seen the discrepancy or if I had missed an earlier reference.

Comment: It's not a spoiler, the dust jacket references Hades

Answer (score 3):

Yes, spoilers:

> Harry is told that the target is Hades in his first briefing from Nicodemus, 5% of the way through the book (can't give you a page number as it's an ebook).

Here's the actual quote:

> "Who?" I asked him. "Whose vault are you knocking over?" "An ancient being of tremendous power," he replied in his roughened voice, his smile widening. "You may know him as Hades, the Lord of the Underworld."

Comment: Your quote is from the end of Chapter 3. Dresden was well aware for most of the book that he was to be heading into the Underworld.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Dresdenverse works a bit differently:
First of all, Hades isn't really Hell as Christianity describes it. The NeverNever is huge and it's all somewhere in there:

Hel / Hell / Helheim - The North European old religions

Hell as portrayed by Christianity

Hades / Underworld according to Greek Mythology

But he at least knew that they were going to burgle Hades. So he at least had to consider going to Underworld as highly probable.

> Also: After finishing the book I realised, that they in theory could have gone there via Daemonreach. Would have been a bit less fussy, don't you think ? ^_^